# Vue.js Transitions and effects executing out of order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition, order-of-execution

I'm making a Tic-Tac-Toe web app. It isn't finished yet as this problem has thrown up a road block. When either X or O wins, it should turn the 3 winning boxes green (this part works if I remove the transition that I want to happen after that). Once the boxes are green, the entire 'Board' table should 'bounce out'. But what's actually happening is that the 'Board' is bouncing out before the 'mark' (X/O) is even shown and the winning boxes turned green. What's not making sense to me is that the focus of the code execution should be from top to bottom but it doesn't appear to be behaving like that. I've tried rearranging the code several different ways and still no luck.

[Here is the Codepen](http://codepen.io/Dirtier/pen/ALxWLy)

And here is the code for those who don't want to click the link :P (**Sorry for the styling, the code snippet doesn't want to work correctly =/**

BTW, thanks in advance!

```js
console.clear();
const log = console.log.bind(console);

const game = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  turn: 'X',
  over: false,
  board: [[{val:'',bg:''}, {val:'',bg:''}, {val:'',bg:''}],
       [{val:'',bg:''}, {val:'',bg:''}, {val:'',bg:''}],
       [{val:'',bg:''}, {val:'',bg:''}, {val:'',bg:''}]],
  windex: [[[0,0], [0,1], [0,2]],
       [[1,0], [1,1], [1,2]],
       [[2,0], [2,1], [2,2]],
       [[0,0], [1,0], [2,0]],
       [[0,1], [1,1], [2,1]],
       [[0,2], [1,2], [2,2]],
       [[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]],
       [[0,2], [1,1], [2,0]]],
  check() {
   const arr = this.board.map( x => x.map( y => y.val ));
   const winArr = this.windex.map( x => x.map( y => this.board[y[0]][y[1]].val ));
   const winner = winArr.map( (x,ind) => {
    if( x.every( y => y == 'X' )) return 'X';
    if( x.every( y => y == 'O' )) return 'O';
   });
   if(winner.includes('X')){
    const inds = this.windex[winner.indexOf('X')];
    inds.forEach( x => {
     this.board[x[0]][x[1]].bg = 'active';
    });
    this.over = true;
   };
   if(winner.includes('O')){
    const inds = this.windex[winner.indexOf('O')];
    inds.forEach( x => {
     this.board[x[0]][x[1]].bg = 'active';
    });
    this.over = true;
   };
   if(arr.every( x => x.every( y => y == 'X' || y == 'O' )))
    this.over = true;
  }
 },
 methods: {
  mark(box) {
   if(this.over) return
   if(box.val === ''){
    box.val = this.turn;
    this.turn = this.turn == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
   } else 
     alert('Invalid turn')
    this.check()
  }
 }
});
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald';

h1 {
 font-family: 'Oswald';
 letter-spacing: 1.5vw;
 text-align: center;
 margin:1vw;
}

table {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 2px;
}

.square {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #6C7A89;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 100px;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family: 'Oswald';
 display: block;
}

.square:hover {
 opacity: .8;
}

td {
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.active {
 background-color: #00B16A;
}

.bounce-leave-active {
  animation: bounce-out 1.5s;
}

@keyframes bounce-out {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.1/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
 <h1>TIC-TAC-TOE</h1>
 <transition name='bounce'>
 <table v-if='!over'>
  <tr v-for='row in board'>
   <td v-for='box in row'>
    <div class='square' 
       v-bind:class='{active:box.bg}' 
       v-on:click='mark(box)'>
     {{box.val}}
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: if you put `this.over = true` in a `setTimeout` it works as you want ... i.e. `setTimeout(() => this.over = true, 0);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked great. Any specific reason why it wasn't working without it though? I've looked everywhere but I'm not even really sure what to Google.

Comment: It may have to do with when the browser gets to repaint

Comment: Hmm ok, well thanks!

Comment: I would have set what you wrote as an answer but I'm new to this and not sure how to set comments as answers, or if you even can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs as a block; the UI doesn't repaint between your setting `active` and `over`, so they happen effectively at the same time as far as the UI is concerned. The `over` triggers the `v-if` binding, so the contents don't get repainted, they just transition out.

Vue provides [`nextTick`](http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-nextTick) to allow you to sequence things. Like `setTimeout(..., 0)`, it takes your command out of the block, but it ensures that a DOM update cycle has happened before executing.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks a lot man. I didn't realize it was running as a block. I had read about nextTick in the Vue docs but didn't know it was applicable here. I thought that was just for triggering events after _everything_ updated.